# How Display Category name in magento menu in two lines?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, category, menu

I am working with magento 1.7 and i have many long categories name in my site. I wish to split every long category name in two line in menu because i would like to display my menu in one row and not two. Any idea ???
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Is the name one word? Then you need [wordwrap()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.wordwrap.php) the name in your template.

If it is not, you can just define the `(max-)width` of the container to limit it.

**You need to limit the width in any case to force a line break!**

Comment: Not one word but many word. After others search i found and other solution that's work with me very well.I just modify my category names in the admin to contain zero-width spaces (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_Width_Space) at strategic intervals.